# LuaLaTeX and \binom

Tags: math-mode, spacing, luatex, amsmath

When compiling the following MWE with `lualatex`,

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\binom{5}{3}\]
\end{document}
```

the numbers inside the binomial coefficient are not centered:

[image: unsymmetric binomial coefficient]

The same happens with `\tbinom`. When compiling with `pdflatex`, I don’t have this problem. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: LuaTeX 0.95.0 and amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.1a (from texlive in the stable repos of Debian)

Comment: With LuaTeX 1.10.0, there is no problem. Probably updating solves your problem.

Comment: That's a quite old luatex. If you really want to use luatex you should better ensure that you have a current tex system - quite a number of bugs have been corrected in the last years.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I updated to LuaTex 1.07.0 and it works now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been solved by updating.